# Java Library to convert pptx to image

Tags: java, image-processing, apache, powerpoint

**Use Case:** I want to convert PPTX file slides into images and post it into my website

I am searching for a library to convert PPTX slides into Images(jpg, png). Suggest me a good java library.

I have tried POI jar, But I am getting alignment and color issues.

Answer (score 1):

[Spire.Presentation for Java](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/presentation-for-java.html) library can be used to convert ppt/pptx to images (for instance, jpg, png, tiff, bmp).

Apart from conversion, the library also supports lots of other manipulations, such as add animations, secure ppt/pptx, add shapes/comments/hyperlinks, create table/chart, add SmartArt graphics and many more. You can explore more about it by visiting the [documentation](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Java/Spire.Presentation-for-Java/Program-Guide/Spire.Presentation-Program-Guide-Content-for-Java.html).

Here is an example shows how to convert a pptx file to images.

```
import com.spire.presentation.Presentation;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class ToImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Presentation ppt = new Presentation();
        ppt.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Sample.pptx");
        //Save pptx file to images
        for (int i = 0; i < ppt.getSlides().getCount(); i++) {
            BufferedImage image = ppt.getSlides().get(i).saveAsImage();
            String fileName = String.format("ToImage-%d.png", i);
            ImageIO.write(image, "PNG",new File(fileName));
        }
        ppt.dispose();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Apache POI

https://gist.github.com/aautar/b3a7f51438a5e478b2f0672d4117a98b.

Also look at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227275/convert-file-pptx-to-image-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.slides is generating accurate images from PPT. But it is not an open-source

Link: [Aspose.Slides](https://docs.aspose.com/display/slidesjava/Slide+Thumbnails+using+Aspose.Slides)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEADTOOLS Document SDK technology in your application.
https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/products/document

You can leverage the RasterCodecs class, which does not require the Microsoft Office interop assemblies, to load each PPT/PPTX slide as a raster image and export each page to JPEG or PNG.

DISCLOSURE: I am an employee of the company offering this toolkit. Also, I did notice this question was a little bit older but the information in this post is for anyone else looking for something similar.

Here is some sample code:

```
String _multipagePPTX = "FILE PATH TO SOURCE PPTX FILE";
RasterCodecs _codecs = new RasterCodecs();
int totalPages = _codecs.getTotalPages(_multipagePPTX);
        
for(int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
{
    String _outputFile = "<FILE_DIRECTORY>\\PPTX(page " + i + ").png";
    RasterImage _image = _codecs.load(_multipagePPTX, i);
    _codecs.save(_image, _outputFile, RasterImageFormat.PNG, _image.getBitsPerPixel());
    _image.dispose();
}
_codecs.dispose();
```

The link below contains a tutorial written in Java that shows how to create an application that utilizes the RasterCodecs class.

https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/java-load-and-save-images.html